# How to avoid do not reply verbiage in sendgrid

Tags: java, spring, email, sendgrid

I am generating an email using sendgrid in my spring application . Everything is working fine but i am getting a verbiage below in the email saying like

```
"Do not reply to this message via e-mail. This address is automated and unattended"
```

Both FROM and TO are my organization ids .Is there anyway i can avoid that verbiage . Please help. Thanks.

Below is my email code

Value in  emailContent is

```
"A new ticket has been created in your queue."
```

But the email i am receiving is

> "A new ticket has been created in your queue. Do not reply to this message via e-mail. This address is automated and unattended."

```
Email from = new Email(fromDl);
Email to = new Email(toDl);
Content content = new Content("text/html", emailContent);
Mail mail = new Mail(from, subject, to, content);
SendGrid sg = new SendGrid(emailKey);
Request request = new Request();
request.setMethod(Method.POST);
request.setEndpoint("mail/send");
request.setBody(mail.build());
Response response = sg.api(request);
```

Comment: How are you sending the email? Are you using a template or sending the HTML/text via the API?

Comment: Updated my question with email code

Comment: If you are adding the content yourself, then SendGrid does not add extra text. Remove that message from `emailContent` and you should be fine.

Comment: emailContent  dose not have it . Is it something added by email DL or Organization ?

Comment: Do you have a footer set up in your [SendGrid account mail settings](https://app.sendgrid.com/settings/mail_settings)?

Comment: no footer set up

Comment: It seems i had the footer set up in account level .  That should fix the issue . Thanks . I can accept it if you make it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally SendGrid will not append anything to the contents of your email. However, you can set up an [account level footer in your account mail settings](https://app.sendgrid.com/settings/mail_settings).

To stop the appended content, remove the footer. Make sure that other emails you are sending don't miss out on that content too though.